# Showing the images in the Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i'm using the gridview to display the images.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="96dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

and the imageview is

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**Note** : I dont want to hardcode the numbers of images to display in single row of gridview because if the screen orientation changed the number changes

When i'm loading m getting the space bewteen the images in the gridview as the below picture[image]

But i dont need the space i want the gridview to appear like the native gallery

Comment: try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: Sorry that doesnt make any change!!

Comment: okay try this: `android:listSelector="@null"` this to your gridview xml and also try `myGridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);`

Comment: or instead of `android:listSelector="@null"` try `@android:color/transparent` as `android:listSelector="@null"` adn `android:listSelector="@android:id/empty"` leads to crash on some devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `layout_width` 
`android:layout_width="match-parent"` instead of `"96dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below tag in `GridView`

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" // changed this value
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

For reference [HorizontalSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:horizontalSpacing) and [VerticalSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:verticalSpacing)

Comment: I dont want any space between the images..as the default gallery looks like!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your gridview xml :

`android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

and also try `myGridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);`